# Why is this equivalent to $p$? $p \vee (p \wedge q) \equiv p$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$p \vee (p \wedge q) \equiv p$$

So, I have tried:

$$(p \vee p) \wedge (p \vee q)$$

Then,

$$p \wedge (p \vee q)$$

I'm getting same equation again. Why is $p \vee (p \wedge q)$ equivalent to $p$?

Comment: have you tried making a truth table?

Comment: $p\land(p\lor q)$ is not the same as $p\lor(p\land q)$.

Comment: In particular, $p\land (p\lor q)$ implies $p$. And $p$ implies $p\land (p\lor q)$.

Comment: The both equation is equivalent to $p$ so my question is why is this isn't it equivalent to $p \wedge q$ or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

$$p \lor (p \land q) = (p \land \top) \lor (p \land q) = p \land (\top \lor q) = p \land \top =p$$